# Установка Codeception

Tags: linux, битрикс, codeception

Добрый день.

Подскажите пожалуйста чего то не удается установить Codeception.
У меня стоит сайт на тестовом сервере. Стоит bitrixVM 5.0. Cам сайт находится по адресу `/home/bitrix/www/`

Через командную строку под root перехожу в корень сайта и ввожу данную команду

> `wget http://codeception.com/codecept.phар`

В корне появился файл `codecept.phar`

[image]

Далее ввожу команду

> `php codecept.phar bootstrаp`

Выводится ошибка

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in /home/bitrix/www/codecept.phar on line 3

[image]

Не пойму, вроде делаю все по [инструкции](http://allframeworks.ru/codeception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, в запускаемом бинарнике PHP отсутствует расширение для работы с Phar (что странно, потому что обычно оно вкомпиливается в бинарник). Phar - это просто архив PHP-проекта для распространения его в виде одного файла; вы можете установить codeception через composer, чтобы гарантированно обойти phar-проблемы: `composer require codeception/codeception:~2.0`. В этом случае исполняемый файл установится в `vendor/bin/codecept` относительно папки проекта, работа с ним ничем не будет отличаться от работы с phar.

> Выводиться
>   находиться

http://tsya.ru -_-

Comment: я правильно понимаю что для того чтобы заработала инструкция для phar нужно установить расширение phar в php ?

Comment: @murad30, похоже на то. Я всегда ставил через composer, правда, он сам распространяется как phar; в общем, проверьте включенные расширения и версию PHP.

Comment: Установку через composer у меня тоже не получается. 
Пробовал с запустить скрипт -  php composer.phar require "codeception/codeception" в корне находится codecept.phar , пробовал и без него вот результат http://i.imgur.com/rbldl2g.png

Comment: @murad30, ну так composer.phar сначала надо скачать с getcomposer.org. Но все равно первым делом проверьте версию PHP, если она ниже 5.4, то codeception у вас не запустится вообще никак.

Comment: Проделывал всю инструкцию как описано вот тут - https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception для phar/ у меня создались все необходимые файлы но пройти дальше не удавалось.

Comment: @murad30, пока вы игнорируете прямые рекомендации, у вас и не будет ничего получаться. Вам так или иначе надо запускать phar-архив (composer либо codecept), отсутствие класса Phar косвенно свидетельствует о том, что версия PHP ниже 5.3, в этом случае у вас совершенно точно ничего не получится запустить, потому что codecept не поддерживал версии раньше 5.3.0, а с версии 2.0 требует 5.4.0 и выше.

Comment: версия php  - PHP Version 5.4.38
http://i.imgur.com/rSKE9bG.png

Comment: @murad30, убедитесь, пожалуйста, что в выводе команды `php -i | grep -i phar` есть строчка `Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled` или что-нибудь аналогичное. Вывод на скриншоте указывает на то, что расширение включено, но это де-факто вывод конфигурации PHP для веб-приложения, для командной строки используется другой файл конфигурации.

Comment: Все, разобрался, удалось установить. Добавил расширение phar и все заработало. Буду разбираться дальше. Вот все проделанные команды для linux  - 1. wget http://codeception.com/codecept.phar 2. chmod +x codecept.phar 3. sudo mv codecept.phar /usr/local/bin/codecept 4. codecept bootstrap

Answer (score -1):

попробуй команду

```
codecept bootstrap
```